# Passing entry_ids to channel:entries tag with low variables entries select

Tags: expressionengine

I'm trying to pass entry_ids to a channel entries tag using low variables entry_select. When i place the following tag by itself in a template it outputs a list of 3 pipe separated entry_ids: `{exp:low_variables:single var='lv-home-groups'}`

however when I add the same code to the following channel:entries tag nothing is output.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="groups" entry_id="{exp:low_variables:single var='lv-home-groups'}" disable="category_fields|pagination"}
code here 
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I've tried early and late parsing but can't get it to work. If i manually place the entry_ids it works fine. I'm trying to avoid using an embedded template for performance reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how: make sure early parsing is enabled for that variable, and then use the *variable syntax* instead of the tag syntax:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="groups" entry_id="{lv-home-groups}"}
code here
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Low, I was just coming to delete this question or answer it myself. Tried one more option which is the one you listed here. I know I've made this mistake before, but can never seem to remember this one.

Comment: CreateSean deleting a question won't help anyone in the future who may have this same question. Answering your own question however will possibly help others and is encouraged assuming no one else has already done so. No shame in asking a question and 10 minutes later the answer pops into your head as it often does for me.

Comment: I second that, answering your own question on SO is encouraged because it will help future searchers. Nothing worse than finding a forum thread saying "don't worry, I solved the problem".